# Potential uses of an empty tuple in Python

Tags: python, immutability, class-variables, immutablearray

I was playing around with the risks of class-level variables in Python, and I thought that the risk of lists as class-level variables can be solved with tuples, for example, an empty tuple.

Take:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    default_sth = []

    def foo(self):
       for sth in self.default_sth:
           pass
```

This is risky because:

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    pass

a = SubClass()
a.default_sth.append(3)

print(BaseClass.default_sth) # [3]
```

Using `None` instead of empty tuple (`tuple()`?) could be instead dangerous because it fails when iterating over it.

Because of immutability, I think this is a good option, but I don't think I've seen anybody talk about this around anywhere. Do you see any flaws with this reasoning? Is it pythonic?

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible that you're looking for class-private members, supported in Python through [name mangling `__leading_double_underscore` names](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)? These are basically class level attributes that are unique to the actual class, and can't be (easily, resp. accidentally) changed by subclasses. See Raymond Hettinger's talk [Class development toolkit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg) for a detailed explanation (name mangling starts at around 33:24).

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/1599111) for a quick example on how name mangling works.

Comment: MMm that's an interesting concept. The problem with that is that I *do* want the variable to be overridable in subclasses, though, without changing the value in the original class.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing class variables with instance variables (which is easy to do since in the absence of an initialized instance variable, the lookup finds the class variable). In this case, you have explicitly said that `default_sth` is a class variable, when you mean to have a default value for an instance variable. Use this instead:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, sth=None):
        if sth is None:
            sth = []

    def foo(self):
       for sth in self.sth:
           pass
```

You might balk a little at having a "hard-coded" default, but you're just adding verbosity by trying to have a separate name for the default value. Just comment and document your `__init__` method to indicate what `sth` is and what its default value should be if no
other value is passed. Don't try to make the default itself configurable unless you have a good reason to.

As far as immutability goes, only the *tuple* is immutable, not the name that refers to it. There's nothing stopping someone from using your original code and saying

```
BaseClass.default_sth = []
```

and you're right back where you started, despite making `default_sth` a tuple to start with.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Do you know if there are any performance differences with doing it in class definition against initialization?

Comment: `self.foo` will always look for `foo` in the object's dictionary, and if that lookup fails, then it checks the class's dictionary. So using class variables as a default for what is really an instance variable imposes the overhead of a failed dictionary lookup on each use.

Comment: Practically speaking, though "explicit is better than implicit", so if something is meant to be an instance variable, initialize it, rather than relying on a fallback to a class variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with using a tuple instead of list is that usually people are choosing to use a list because they actually want list semantics; you can't append to a tuple, sort it in place, remove items from it, etc. If you want your class-level list attribute to not be shared with sub-classes, the sub-class can just make its own copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class SubClass(BaseClass):
    default_sth = deepcopy(BaseClass.default_sth)  # now SubClass has its own copy.
```

Then your example will output `[]`, which is the behavior you would prefer. If you use a tuple in `BaseClass`, your example will throw an `AttributeError` (because it tries to call `append` on a tuple), and the code would need to change to this to do the equivalent of an `append`:

```
a = SubClass()
a.default_sth = tuple(list(a.default_sth) + [3])
```

Which is kind of a pain to write and not very efficient since you're doing a bunch of copying to convert from tuple -> list -> tuple.

Comment: I hadn't thought somebody might want list semantics. I'll take that into account!  +1 for the `deepcopy` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Mutable default variables are well-known fart in otherwise so beautiful Python.

E.g.

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/16/python-insight-beware-of-mutable-default-values-for-arguments/

["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/

Solutions include

- Initialize everything in `__init__` - don't use class-level variables unless you really mean global variables
- Pass in `None` and convert it to list when accessed first time

Comment: This isn't an issue with default parameter values; it's just a simple class variable.

Comment: did you mean to say "well-known *wart*"? :)